# Rectangle2D getY() returns value less than getMaxY()

Tags: java, geometry, awt

As I interpret the documentation, [getY()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.Double.html#getY%28%29) is supposed to return the upper-left hand Y coordinate of a rectangle; i.e the biggest Y coordinate. However, when calling [getMaxY()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/RectangularShape.html#getMaxY%28%29) (which is inherited from the RectangularShape class) I get back a bigger value!

In code:

```
Path2D bg = polygons.get(polyId2GeoId.get(id));
Rectangle2D bgBox = bg.getBounds2D();
boolean omgwtfbbqrsvp = bgBox.getY()<bgBox.getMaxY();
```

omgwtfbbqrsvp is true... What am I missing here?

My x values contain negative numbers idk if that makes a difference. It sames like bgBox.getY() == bgBox.getMinY() (which is wrong if getY is **upper** coord) but bgBox.getX() == bgBox.getMinX() (which is correct if getX is **left** coord). The heights and widths appear correct.

Thanks!

Comment: Wtf why did you use omgwtfbbqrsvp as a variable name? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the coordinate system used here has its point (0,0) on the upper left corner. The point (n,n) is on the lower right corner.